# How to map Eloquent with other tables?

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

This is the first time when i use ORM, so i wondering if it is possible to map it to other tables...

For example i have currently logged user. It is connected to the `POSTS` table through links table. For example if i want to select posts i do sql like this:

```
SELECT
    `posts`.`id`', `posts`.`Name`, `posts`.`Description`
FROM
    `links`,
    `posts`
WHERE
    `links`.`user_id` = 1 AND `links`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
```

How to extend Eloquent that if i request `Posts::all()` it would return posts only for current user...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) in your `POST` modal

```
public function scopeOfUser($query,$user_id)
{
    return $query->join('links', 'links.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
       ->where('links.user_id', '=', $user_id)
       ->select('posts.id', 'posts.Name', 'posts.Description');
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$posts = POST::OfUser(1)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your post is a bit confusing but I hope my answer addresses it as you expect.

## Warning:

Please refer to Laravel's (Many to Many) [Relationship documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) for details.

To make things simple and comply with the *Laravel convention*, I strongly suggest you to use `post_user`instead of `link` as the **pivot table** (`post_user` table should have `user_id` and `post_id` as columns).

You don't have to define a corresponding pivot model (that's the convention).

The following models are meant to map to respectfully the tables `users` and `posts`.

## User Model:

in app/model/user.php (already there, just add the relationship definition)

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    ...

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }

    ...

}
```

## Post Model:

in app/models/post.php (to be created of course).

```
...

class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}

...
```

## Retrieval of a user's posts:

Usually, you do the following in Laravel to get the current logged user:

```
$user = Auth::user(); // a User model / record
```

Assuming $user is of type User (Model), you can retrieve all its posts using:

```
$user->posts(); // a Collection
```